# Easy bit-wise operation on bit string in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, bit-manipulation

I'm working on an iOS app that uses a lot of long bit strings (100b) and a lot of bitwise operations. I know that there is very nice bitset class in c++ but I can't include the header file in Xcode. Apple has a CFBitVector class that supports bit string, but it does not have bitwise manipulation. Is there a way that I can use bit string and make bitwise operation as easy as if I'm dealing with unsigned int (so that bitwise operation is simply a & b)?

Right now what I have is using CFBitVector and make a bunch of function calls for bitwise and, bitwise or, and bitwise not. But in this case a simple one-line bitwise manipulation can result into a 4-line function calling creating a lot of temporary variables I don't really need.

Comment: Why can't you use the C++? Did you make sure you were compiling as Objective-C++ and not just Objective-C? You can either change your filename (from .m to .mm) or change an Xcode setting.

Comment: You can use smae c++ class by changing file extension to .mm

Comment: OMG really? how do I do this? I thought changing the filename to .mm would crash the whole thing.

Comment: how do I change the Xcode setting?

Comment: @TengyuLiu: You can simply rename the file in the Xcode Project Navigator.

Comment: @MartinR I'm trying to #include <bitset> in my .h file and it can't find the file. What should I do?

Comment: @TengyuLiu: Is the .h file included by other (non-C++) files as well? You can include `<bitset>` only from C++ or Objective-C++ files (or from .h files which are only included from C++ or Objective-C++ files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(From the comments:)* You can mix Objective-C and C++ code if you compile the file
as Objective-C++: Simply rename the file extension from .m to .mm in the Xcode project
navigator.

When including C++ header files such as `<bitset>` in your .h file, keep in mind that this
will only work if the .h file is included by (Objective-)C++ files, not if it is included
by Objective-C files.